# How to Count the number of replies from a comment in a given photo using Django Query?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am trying to achieve is to get all comments based on photo_id, and count the **total replies** at the same time.

**models.py:**

```py
    class PhotoComment(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        photo = models.ForeignKey(UserPhoto,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        comment_text = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
        comment_reply = models.ForeignKey('self',related_name='replies',blank=True,null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
        ...
        def __str__(self):
            return '%s(photo_%s)' %(self.user,self.photo)
```

**views.py:**

```
    class PhotoCommentView(APIView):
        def patch(self,request,formate=None):
            photo_id = request.data.get('photo_id')
            all_comment = list(PhotoComment.objects.filter(photo__id = photo_id,comment_reply = None).values('id','user__username','comment_text','user__profile__profile_pic','vote_upvote').annotate(total_reply = Count('comment_reply')))
            return Response({"Data" : all_comment},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Real result is like this:**

```
    {
        "Data": [
            {
                "id": 12,
                "user__username": "pradip",
                "comment_text": "this is awesome pic bro....",
                "user__profile__profile_pic": "profile_pic/gyroscope_HUq0uJ0.png",
                "vote_upvote": 2,
                "total_reply": 0⬅⬅⬅⬅
            },
            ...
               ]
    }
```

**What I want for result is like this**(Here comment id **12** contain total **3** replies.):

```
     {
            "Data": [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "user__username": "pradip",
                    "comment_text": "this is awesome pic bro....",
                    "user__profile__profile_pic": "profile_pic/gyroscope_HUq0uJ0.png",
                    "vote_upvote": 2,
                    "total_reply": 3⬅⬅⬅⬅
                },
                ....
                    ]
     }
```

I have no idea with this problem I need some help.

If you know any other easy or recommended solution to achieve this please tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try adding that property like you added the other ones?

Comment: `QuerySet.values()` is used when you don't want model instances. If you want to access properties or methods on model instances, then don't use `values`.

Comment: It's also possible to use [queryset annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) instead of the model property. However, I don't really understand what `total_reply` is supposed to do, so I can't suggest a alternative query to you. `comment_reply = self.user` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: What does `comment_reply = self.user` mean anyway? `comment_reply` is a Foreign Key to self meaning an instance of `PhotoComment` while `self.user` is an Foreign Key to `User` and hence an instance to it.

Comment: @HåkenLid @Abdul Aziz Barkat  Sir thank you for your reply.`comment_reply = self.user` doesn't any make sense I accept. it's my mistake. I totally updated my question. Please check what I wanna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `SerializerMethodField()` in `serializer` to count comment reply.

**serializers.py:**

```
class ShowCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        total_reply = SerializerMethodField()
        user_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
        profile_pic = serializers.CharField(source='user.profile.profile_pic')
            
        class Meta:
            model = PhotoComment
            fields = ('id','user_name','profile_pic','comment_text','total_reply','created_date')
            read_only_fields = fields
            
        def get_total_reply(self, obj):
            total = obj.replies.count()
            return total
```

**views.py:**

```
class PhotoCommentView(APIView):
    def patch(self,request,formate=None):
        photo_id = request.data.get('photo_id')
        comment_inst = PhotoComment.objects.filter(photo = photo_id,comment_reply=None)
        serializer = ShowCommentSerializer(comment_inst,many=True)
        return Response({"Data" : serializer.data},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "id": 29,
            "user_name": "admin",
            "profile_pic": "profile_pic/Airbus.png",
            "comment_text": "good bro....",
            "total_reply": 3,
            "created_date": "2021-03-10T02:25:43.940127+05:30"
        },
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, properties are refering to a specific object instance. Querysets are used to do things on a range of objects.

Therefore to replicate for a queryset the property you defined for an object instance, you need to setup an annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Count
all_comment = list(PhotoComment.objects.annotate(total=Count('comment_reply')
   ).filter(photo__id =  request.data.get('photo_id')
   ).values('id','comment_text','total'))
```

Hope the general principle explained here will enable you to get to where you want to go

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please check my updated question. sorry for late reply.